# Doubt with the library esp8266wifi and Station Mode

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I have been working for a while with the **ESP8266** I have a question:

According to the online documentation of GitHub from the [esp8266wifi library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/esp8266wifi/station-class.rst) I can initialize the WiFi in *Station* mode to (obviously) connect to a nearby AP, I can initialize the station mode in 3 "different ways":

- `WiFi.begin ()`: The module initializes the *Station* mode and connects to the last network that is connected, because the credentials (SSID and Password) are stored in its internal memory (flash?).
- `WiFi.begin (ssid, password)`: The module initializes the *Station* mode and connects to the network with "ssid" and "password".
- `WiFi.begin (ssid, password, channel, bssid, connect)`: The same as the previous one, only that you pass more parameters: the one that interests me is the bssid, which is the **MAC address** of the AP to which I am going to connect.

Now comes the question: if I wanted to use the *last* mode, because I want to make sure that the **ESP** connects **ONLY** to an AP (a kind of MAC filtering), I also have to specify the channel and set the connect parameter? Or I can simply use something like this:

```
WiFi.begin ("MyOwnNetwork", "123456789", "00: 1B: 44: 11: 3A: B7")
```

I can not prove it right now, I do not have the module in my hands.

Comment: type of parameter bssid is  const uint8_t* (byte array)

Comment: the configuration is saved to flash https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/arduino-esp8266/docs_to_readthedocs/arduino-esp8266.pdf

Comment: the configuration is saved including the bssid

Comment: What do you mean with: "type of parameter bssid is const uint8_t* (byte array)", the way I wrote the sentence is wrong? Could you give some example? Thanks!

Comment: anything inside quote marks `""` is a string .... google `c++ byte array` ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240405/byte-array-assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function prototype:

[image: Function]

Per C++ rules, in order to supply an argument for `bssid`, you have to pass an argument for `channel` as well, but `connect` is optional since it's positioned after your target argument. This should not be a problem though since you can just pass the default value of `channel` (i.e. 0) into the function; the `channel` argument is only relevant if you enter a value between 1 and 13 inclusive.

So your call should basically look like:

```
char ssid[] = "ssid";
char pwd[] = "pwd";
uint8_t bssid[] = {0x00, 0x1b, 0x44, 0x11, 0x3a, 0xb7};
WiFi.begin(ssid, pwd, 0, bssid);
```

Comment: Great answer!!! Just the one I was looking for!!! Thanks!!!!!